# How to disable decompression in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using the HTTP Action in a Logic App. **I want the response body to be compressed in the next step, I'm just going to save the response gzipped.** The API I'm calling requires Accept-Encoding to be gzip (or deflate), it will return 406 if that header is missing in the request.

I noticed that there is an option on the HTTP Action that disables automatic decompression.

[image: Disable decompression]

However, when that option is selected it also seems to remove the Accept-Encoding header from the request, which causes the action to fail (because of 406). Adding the header manually does not seem to work either, the Logic app [removes these headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#omitted-http-headers).

How do I keep the gzip compression in the output from the action?

Comment: To keep the gzip compression in the output from the HTTP Action in an Azure Logic App, you should not select the "Disable automatic decompression" option. This option removes the Accept-Encoding header from the request, causing the action to fail. Instead, you can leave this option unchecked and add the Accept-Encoding header manually with a value of "gzip" or "deflate", depending on the API's requirements. According to the documentation, the Logic App removes some headers, but it does not mention removing the Accept-Encoding header. Therefore, adding this header manually should work.

Comment: References:

-   [Azure Logic Apps: HTTP Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#http-action)

Comment: It doesn't work. The link specifies that it removes "Accept-* headers except for Accept-version" in Known Issues in the bottom of the document.